# configuring iptables for Squid's tcp_outgoing_address on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, linux-networking, squid

IPs on my machine

```
root@poweredge:/var/log/squid# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:4f:cd:c1:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.212/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21e:4fff:fecd:c15f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlx74da388c32c7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:da:38:8c:32:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.11.107/24 brd 172.16.11.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx74da388c32c7
       valid_lft 3531sec preferred_lft 3531sec
    inet6 fe80::4e86:c190:1e45:4722/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I want to connect to Squid proxy using the `192.168.1.212` and if I am connecting using port 11000, I want squid to have the traffic go out of the `172.16.11.107` IP

Below is the relevant part of my squid.conf

```
http_port 11000 name=port_11000
acl port_11000_acl myportname port_11000
tcp_outgoing_address 172.16.11.107 port_11000_acl
```

From what I have read the above configuration should be enough for Squid, but on Linux machines, I also need to use iptables. I have never used IP tables.

What would I need to do with iptables to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Policy Routing to do this.
Frist, add the route table in file /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
eg:

```
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
2   squid
```

For example, the following one commands will both look at the same routing table, assuming you have performed the editing above:

```
ip route list table squid
```

Since I entered ip route list table squid, the output will be a new command line. There is nothing in the table to list. 
populate each of the tables with a route. I will use the local interface address 
172.16.11.0/24 in your infomathin

```
/sbin/ip rule add from wlx74da388c32c7 pref 1000 table squid
/sbin/ip route add table 172.16.11.0/24 default via 172.16.11.1
```

This assume that your wlx74da388c32c7 interface gateway is 172.16.11.1
Then it works~